# Change logged in user's role after Contact Form 7 submission

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am trying to change the user role of the logged in user when they submit a Contact Form 7 form.

I compiled this from various similar solutions that I found, but none of them work for me. I don't see any errors, but it does not update the user role.

```
    function wpcf7_before_send_mail_function( $contact_form, $abort, $submission ) {

    $post_id = $submission->get_meta('container_post_id');
    $form_id = $contact_form->id();

    // do something   
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $user_id = $user->ID;
        $user_meta = get_userdata($user_id);
        $user_roles = $user_meta->roles;

        if ( $form_id == 2368 ) {
            
                 $user_id = wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id, 'role' => 'paid' ) );
           
        }
    }

    return $contact_form;
    
}
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_before_send_mail_function', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: First thing...It's an action hook, not a filter.

Comment: Thanks @HowardE, I have updated to 'add_action'. 
Still not working though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't actually test this, but I think this should work for you.

So instead of `wp_update_user` you can use the function `set_role()` which is a member of the USER Class

```
function wpcf7_before_send_mail_function($contact_form, $abort, $submission) {

    $form_id = $contact_form->id();
    
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && $form_id === 2368) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $user->set_role('paid');
    }

}
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_before_send_mail_function', 10, 3 );
```

> There is a setting in Contact Form 7 where you have to add: "subscribers_only: true" to the additional settings tab. Without this the logged-in check and the "wp_get_current_user" do not function correctly.

Comment: Thanks Howard. This looks much cleaner.

Comment: If this works for you... please accept the answer, and give it an upvote

Comment: It doesn't work for me as it is. 
But I think I may have narrowed down what my issue is...
If I remove "is_user_logged_in()" 
and use "$user = new WP_User( 264 );" 
instead of "$user = wp_get_current_user();" 
Then it works to change the user role. 
So I think I maybe have an issue with it detecting that I am actually logged in? I definitely am logged in so puzzled why this wont work.

Comment: Since this is an ajax action, you might want to pass the userid in the form as a hidden field.

Comment: I figured it out! Howard, your code was correct. There is a setting in Contact Form 7 where you have to add: "subscribers_only: true" to the additional settings tab. Once this is added the "is_user_logged_in" check and the "wp_get_current_user" both work as expected. (https://contactform7.com/additional-settings/)

I found a snippet in the CF7 files that hints at this: "[Use subscribers-only mode] Otherwise, the logged-in user data will be reset by the WP REST API, and a blank text will replace the tag."