# Update user meta after cf7 submit WP

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, metadata, contact-form-7

I want to substract 1 from user meta after cf7 form submittion. I've got this function but it doesn't work:

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'process_contact_form_data' );
function process_contact_form_data( $contact_data ){

   $user_last = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'QuestionAvailiable', true ); 
    $user_last_sum =  $user_last - 1;
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'QuestionAvailiable', $user_last_sum);          
}
```

`QuestionAvailiable` is still 3 after form submit, not 2. What's wrong?

Comment: You haven't passed the `$user_id` to your function.

Comment: @HowardE I have. I edited question

Comment: @HowardE I've created hidden your-id input and passed id of user to it. How can I get this ID in `wpcf7_before_send_mail` hook?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68831548/change-logged-in-users-role-after-contact-form-7-submission/68834466#68834466

Comment: @HowardE In that question he got user object as `wp_get_current_user()`. I changed $user_id to `$user_id = wp_get_current_user()->id;`. It doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current user id is passed through the form by hidden `meta` fields which are accessible via the method `get_meta(field)`

This should work for you.

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'process_contact_form_data' );
function process_contact_form_data( $contact_data ) {
    $user_last     = get_user_meta( $contact_data->get_meta( 'current_user_id' ), 'QuestionAvailiable', true );
    $user_last_sum = absint( $user_last ) - 1;
    update_user_meta( $contact_data->get_meta( 'current_user_id' ), 'QuestionAvailiable', $user_last_sum );
}
```

For reference, the following are the meta fields that are available to the `$contact_form` object which is the first parameter of the `wpcf7_before_send_mail` hook.

```php
array(
    'timestamp'         => integer,
    'remote_ip'         => string,
    'remote_port'       => integer,
    'user_agent'        => string,
    'url'               => 'current_url',
    'unit_tag'          => string,
    'container_post_id' => integer,
    'current_user_id'   => integer,
    'do_not_store'      => bool,
);
```

Comment: I've already solved id by redirecting to link with parameters after submit where meta is updating. But thank you, this solution perhaps will help somebody